# Image is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Given an entire function $f$ whose real part is bounded. How can I show that the image of $f$ is not dense in $\mathbb{C}$?

One attempt is to define $g(z):=f(1/z)$ for $z\neq 0$. Then how can I construct such an $\epsilon$ in order to show that $|z-z_0|>|\epsilon|$ for all $z\in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$. Then$$\bigl\lvert g(z)\bigr\rvert=e^{\operatorname{Re}(f(z))}$$and therefore $g$ is a bounded entire function. Therefore, by Liouville's theorem, it is constant. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Then I only know that $f(z)$ is also constant function. Is the image of a constant function then trivially not dense in $\mathbb{C}$??

Comment: Yes, it is trivial.

Comment: ok, I just thought it would be more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: Imo this is in very poor taste, making it look like something that's honestly obvious from the definition has something to do with a non-trivial theorem...

Comment: You are right. I had this idea and then I did not think about it again. I have just upvoted the other answer.

Answer (score 4):

If the real part of $f$ is bounded, say $\operatorname{Re}f(z)<M$ for some $M\in \Bbb R$, then there is no $z$ such that $|f(z) - (M+1)|<1$, which shows that the image of $f$ is not dense in $\Bbb C$.

More geometrically (but essentially the same argument), if the image of $f$ is contained in the part of the complex plane to the left of the vertical line through the real number $M$, then we can't get function values arbitrarily close to $M+1$.